# Does each NFT for a wallet have a unique Associated Token Account?

Tags: nft, metaplex-js

I've just received two NFTs, using the same Solana wallet. Using SolScan, [I can see each NFT is in their own Associated Token Account (there's a third Associated Token Account on the wallet for USDC)](https://solscan.io/account/5FHwkrdxntdK24hgQU8qgBjn35Y1zwhz1GZwCkP2UJnM). I can see the same thing happens - each new NFT ends up in a new ATA - when I mint NFTs using [metaplex `create()`](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create).

[image]

My question is - is this normal? **Is there always an ATA with a balance of 1 token per NFT owned by a wallet?** - so if I own 26 NFTs I will have 26 ATAs for those NFTs?

The Metaplex docs don't really discuss ATAs in detail and the SPL token docs seem focused on currency-like tokens rather than NFTs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, a new ATA is created for any NFT that your wallet owns. The reason for this is that NFTs are unique tokens and thus have distinct `mints`. Just as the mint for a `sol` token is different from that for a `usdc` token, the mint of any NFT token is different from every other.